# Fit an Picture in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to put a picture in my DataGrid. So I used a DataGridTemplateColumn but the Result is "glitchy".

Here is my wpf extract code :

```
<DataGrid MinRowHeight="24" x:Name="ListFamily" Grid.Column="1" 
                  Margin="2" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" 
                  SelectionChanged="ListFamily_SelectionChanged" 
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                  CanUserSortColumns="False" Grid.Row="1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- some datagridcolumn -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
               <Label Content="{x:Static res:StringResources.language}" ToolTip="{x:Static tt:TooltipStrings.language}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <Image Source="{Binding Language, Converter={StaticResource StringToPicture}}" Height="{Binding RowHeight, ElementName=ListFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Uniform"/>
               </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
               <Style>
                   <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
               </Style>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and here is what I get :

[image: Picture size is glitching ?]

I triend to bind RowHeight of the DataGrid but without luck. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Thibaud

Comment: I get the same result :/

Comment: I tried without the <DataGridTemplateColumn.Style> and it's working --' I feel wird now ^^ Thank you @ASh , you gave me the good tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code is working :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
      <Label Content="{x:Static res:StringResources.language}" ToolTip="{x:Static tt:TooltipStrings.language}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Image Source="{Binding Language, Converter={StaticResource StringToPicture}}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```